# CSS3 Color Styling Remains After Removing Class With Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a element that I change the color styling dynamically with Javacsript. The id `#clock` and id `#quantity` sets the color. When a condition changes, I change the color styling with Javacsript by adding a class. When the condition changes back, I remove the class. However, the issue is after removing the class the color style of the removed class remains rather than the color styled by the previous 2 id's.

I could resolve this by remove the id's and re-applying them dynamically with Javascript. But, I was wondering if there was a more efficient solution?

```
<div id="clock">
    <div id="top-gradient"></div>
    <div id="time">
        <span id="zen9" class="quantity"></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="zentext">Server Monitor</div> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
bar = document.getElementById(id);
etop = bar.parentNode.parentElement;
ebottom = bar.parentNode.previousElementSibling;
etext = bar.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[5];
if ( value >= threshold[id] && !(bar.classList.contains("zenRed"))) {
    bar.classList.add("redZen");
    etop.classList.add("redZenTop");
    ebottom.classList.add("redZenBottom");
    etext.classList.add("redZenText");
} else if ( value < threshold[id] && (bar.classList.contains("zenRed"))) {
    bar.classList.remove("redZen");
    etop.classList.remove("redZenTop");
    ebottom.classList.remove("redZenBottom");
    etext.classList.remove("redZenText");
}
```

Comment: Would you mind exporting this to a JSFiddle? Alongside your CSS as well?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle with your CSS?

Comment: That wont fixe anything but JQuery would make that easier to read and easier to debugg.

Comment: If you dont put up some CSS, it gets hard to try and debug. As those other people said, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Sebastien jQuery won't make it easier to read nor easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really gave us much information. However i understand you want to add a class on a condition and remove the same class on a condition.

First of all there is no element that has the id #quantity, it's a class.

Anyway, with the toggle function of [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.classList) you can add remove the class depending if it is already asigned.

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var bar =  document.getElementById('clock');
var foo =  document.getElementById('time');

bar.classList.toggle('redZen');
foo.classList.toggle('pinkZen');
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jhM8/)**